# C++ Program with pointers not working

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I am a beginner and am stuck. I have written this and so far it is not working. After "Add or Remove Trader" it does nothing. Any help or tidbits on how to make this functional would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct Department{
string deptName;
int numTraders;     
};

void addTraders(Department *, int );
void removeTraders(Department *, int);

int main(){

char addOrRemove;
Department departments[10] = {
    {"Bank Loan", 10},
    {"Conservative Allocation", 9},
    {"Europe Stock", 10},
    {"Domestic", 21},
    {"Asia", 10},
    {"Large Growth", 5},
    {"Long-term Bond", 5},
    {"Money Market", 25},
    {"Emerging Market", 18},
    {"Large Blend", 12}
};

int choice, numberToAdd, numberToRemove;

Department* p_departments = departments;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout << "Department # " << (i + 1) << ", Name: " << p_departments[i].deptName <<
        ", Traders: " << p_departments[i].numTraders << endl;
}
cout << endl;

do{

cout << "Enter 0 to quit, or choose a department number: ";
cin >> choice;

cout << "Add or remove traders (A or R) ? ";
cin >> addOrRemove;

if(addOrRemove == 'A' || 'a'){
    cout << "how many traders to add" << endl;
    cin >> numberToAdd;
    addTraders(&departments[choice-1] ,numberToAdd);
}
else if(addOrRemove == 'R' || 'r'){
    cout << "how many traders to remove" << endl;
    cin >> numberToRemove;
    removeTraders(&departments[choice-1],numberToRemove);
}
else{
    cout << addOrRemove << " is not a valid selection. \n";
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout << "Department # " << (i + 1) << ", Name: " << p_departments[i].deptName <<
        ", Traders: " << p_departments[i].numTraders << endl;
}
cout << endl;

}while(count != 0);

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void addTraders(Department *dept, int numAdd){

dept->numTraders += numAdd;
}

void removeTraders(Department *dept, int numRemove){

dept->numTraders += numRemove;
}
```

Comment: `if(addOrRemove == 'A' || 'a')` does not do what you think and other `if`

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger? Where does your program start to missbehave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following condition is always evaluated as `true`; even if it's `false || 'a'`, `'a'` ~> `true`:

```
if(addOrRemove == 'A' || 'a'){ ...
```

it was meant to be:

```
if(addOrRemove == 'A' || addOrRemove == 'a'){ ...
```

However when `addOrRemove` is declared as a `char`, then:

```
cin >> addOrRemove;
```

might just read a new-line character or some white space. It would be probably more reasonable to declare `addOrRemove` as `std::string` and change your condition to:

```
if(addOrRemove == "A" || addOrRemove == "a"){ ...
```

And after you read `choice` and it's `0`, you should `break` your loop so that it won't try to access element at index `0 - 1`:

```
cin >> choice;
if (choice == 0) break;   // <-- THIS
```

Comment: Thank you I made those changes. It should have said choice and not count, however my program still terminates(press any key to continue after I enter A or R) after Add or Remove trader.

Comment: @user2535063: Check my answer now. If this doesn't help, then I have no idea what exactly goes wrong. Try to debug it.

Comment: I should add that the program is working as intended now, still need to add a few input validations but the changes you suggested worked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all instead of

```
if(addOrRemove == 'A' || 'a'){
```

you should write

```
if(addOrRemove == 'A' || addOrRemove == 'a'){
```

And secondly you should define variable count because it seems that the compiler thinks that count - is name of standard algorithm std::count.